# C++ | Reuse conditions

Tags: c++, optimization, conditional-statements, redundancy

I'm currently writing a simple calculator program in C++, and whenever I want to check if the `cin` values are valid, and give feedback to user if said input is invalid, I have to reuse the condition in both my do-while loop and its nested if statement giving the feedback. This feels redundant.

Here's the code in question:

```
do  {
    cout << "Enter operator: "; cin >> operatorSign;

    if ( operatorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/' 
        && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-' )
        cout << "Must be a valid operator sign (*, /, + or -).\a\n\n";

} while ( operatorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/' 
       && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-' );
```

As you can see, I've reused the exact same condition twice for feedback (if) **and** to continue loop if input is invalid. My question is, how can you reduce the redundancy of the code above? Can you store conditions in a variable or something?

Comment: You could even make it `} while (true);` and `break` when the condition isn't true

Comment: Build with optimizations enabled, and look at the generated code to see if the compiler "reuse" the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
bool isValid;
do  {
    isValid = true;
    cout << "Enter operator: "; 
    cin >> operatorSign;

    if ( operatorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/' && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-' )
    {
        cout << "Must be a valid operator sign (*, /, + or -).\a\n\n";
        isValid = false;
    }

} while (!isValid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write a function

```
bool isOpInvalid(char op) {
    return op != '*' && op != '/' && op != '+' && op != '-';
}
```

and change the loop to

```
do {
   cout << "Enter operator: ";
   cin >> operatorSign;

   if (isOpInvalid(operatorSign))
      cout << "Must be a valid operator sign (*, /, + or -).\a\n\n";

} while (isOpInvalid(operatorSign));
```

or write a `while` loop

```
while (true) {
    cout << "Enter operator: ";
    cin >> operatorSign;

    if (operatorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/'
            && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-')
        cout << "Must be a valid operator sign (*, /, + or -).\a\n\n";
    else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store conditions in a variable. Sort of. `bool` type variables in C++ can store `true`/`false` values.

```
bool isInvalid = peratorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/' 
                 && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-';
```

and then `if (isInvalid)` and `while (isInvalid)`
You should look at where you set the variable though.

However, what I'd do is to create a function that checks if the choice is valid and call it.

```
bool isInvalid(operatorSign)
{
   return peratorSign != '*' && operatorSign != '/' 
          && operatorSign != '+' && operatorSign != '-';
}
```

and then `if (isInvalid(operatorSign))` and `while (isInvalid(operatorSign))`

I didn't want to change it too much at a time but it seems better to create `isValid` / `isValid()` and use their negation.

Answer (score 1):

Another of many ways, using a lambda:

```
// use zero value as an error indicator and initial condition
char operatorSign = '\0';

auto check_ok = [&]
{
    switch(operatorSign)
    {
        case '*': case '/': case '+': case '-':
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Must be a valid operator sign (*, /, + or -).\a\n\n";
            operatorSign = '\0';
            break;
    }
};

while(!operatorSign)  
{
    cout << "Enter operator: "; cin >> operatorSign;
    check_ok();
}
```